# It's okay to make a db conection multiple times? PHP - MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm using a class called MyMysqli to conect, make queries, etc.

MyMysqli.php:

```
...
public function query($query){
    $this->total_queries++;
    $result= mysqli_query($this->conection, $query);
    if(!$result){
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($this->conection);
        exit;
    }
    return $result;
}
...
...
        public function free(){
            mysqli_free_result($this->result);
        }
...
```

And I have other class to define Users.
Inside it, I have a public function to modify some data of the user:

```
public function makeActive($id){
    if($this->userExists($id)){
        $db = new MyMysqli;
        $db->query("UPDATE users SET userActive =1 WHERE idUser=".$id);
        $db->free();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the function userExists //checks if an user exists :

```
public function userExists($id){
    $db = new MyMysqli;
    $db->query("SELECT idUser FROM users WHERE idUser=".$id);
    if($db->num_rows($db->query) === 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    $db->free();
}
```

So, as you can see, I'm calling to new MyMysqli 2 times in a function, it's okay to do that ? or I should'nt use another function to check if an user exists, including the check into makeActive function?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You should probably translate those code snippets to english if you hope on an answer. To answer your question, there is overhead in connecting to a database, do the connection stuff once, then use that connection multiple times.

Comment: You should only open one connection to the db per page request unless you want problems

Comment: Translated, thank you! 
@developerwjk, even if I free the result?, thank you!

Comment: Each time you open and close a connection you're adding extra processing time you wouldn't have if you had just kept the connection open as a global variable, or passed a connection object into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for this is to use the mysqli persistant connection.

When you are creating the connection to the mysql, use the following example.

```
mysqli_connect('p:servername', 'username', 'password', 'database', port);
```

*To open a persistent connection you must prepend `p:` to the hostname when connecting.*

---

According to the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

> The idea behind persistent connections is that a connection between a
>   client process and a database can be reused by a client process,
>   rather than being created and destroyed multiple times. This reduces
>   the overhead of creating fresh connections every time one is required,
>   as unused connections are cached and ready to be reused.

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like (I may be wrong) It looks like a collection of Utility Methods, It would probably be better to pass the connection into each method so you can use them across different connections with the same Schema, This would also help with your multiple Connections since you would only need to maintain one per database.